# Verilog Parallel Check and Assignment Across Dissimilar Sized Shift Registers

Tags: loops, verilog

I'm looking to perform the cross-correlation*  operation using an FPGA.

The secific part that I am currently struggling with is the multiplication piece.  I want to multiply each 8-bit element of a nx8 shift register that uses excess or offset representation** against a nx1 shift register where I treat 0s as a -1 for the purposes of multiplication.

Now if I was doing that for a single element, I might do something like this for the operation:

```
input [7:0] dataIn;

input refIn;

output [7:0] dataOut;

wire [7:0] dataOut;
wire [7:0] invertedData;

assign invertedData = 8'd0 - dataIn;
assign dataOut <= refIn ? dataIn : invertedData;
```

What I'm wondering is how do I scale this to 4, 8, n elements?

My first though was to use a for loop like this:

```
for(loop=0; loop < n; loop = loop+1)
begin
    assign invertedData[loop*8+7:loop*8] = 8'd0 - dataIn[loop*8+7:n*8];
    assign dataOut[loop*8+7:loop*8] <= refIn[loop] ? dataIn[loop*8+7:loop*8] : invertedData[loop*8+7:loop*8];
end
```

This doesn't compile, but that's more or less the idea, and I can't seem to find the right syntax to do what I want.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation

** http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~patrice/210-2006/210%20LN04_2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(loop=0; loop < n; loop = loop+1)
begin
    assign invertedData[n*8+7:n*8] = 8'd0 - dataIn[n*8+7:n*8];
    assign dataOut[n*8+7:n*8] <= refIn[n] ? dataIn[n*8+7:n*8] : invertedData[n*8+7:n*8];
end
```

There's a few issues with this, but I think you can make this work.

1. You can't have 'assign' statements in a for loop. A for loop is meant to be used inside a `begin`/`end` block, so you need to change invertedData/dataOut from `wire` type to `reg` type, and remove the assign statements.
2. You generally can't have variable part-selects, unless you use the special constant-width selection operator (verilog-2001 support required). That would look like this: `dataIn[n*8 +:8]`, which means: *select 8 bits starting from n*8*.
3. I don't know about your algorithm, but it looks like loop/n are backwards in your statement. You should be incrementing n, not loop variable (or else all statements will be operating on the same part-select).

So considering those points I believe this should compile for you:

```
always @* begin
    for(n=0; n< max_loops ; n=n+1)
    begin
        invertedData[n*8 +:8] = 8'd0 - dataIn[n*8 +:8];
        dataOut[n*8 +:8] <= refIn[n] ? dataIn[n*8 +:8] : invertedData[n*8 +:8];
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll give it a shot.  As for point 3, swap n for loop in the assign statements within the loop.  I meant n to be any constant value to represent the size of the array.